# How to refer to another user's properties in Nix expression?

Tags: nixos, nix

I want to set root's `startGid` and `startUid` to the GID and UID of another user. How can I do that **without hardcoding them?** I've tried several variations on the following:

```
  users.users = {
    root = {
      subGidRanges = [
        {
          count = 1;
          startGid = users.users.username.group;
        }
      ];
      subUidRanges = [
        {
          count = 1;
          startUid = config.ids.uids.username;
        }
      ];
    };
    username = {
      isNormalUser = true;
    };
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
  users.users = {
    root = {
      subGidRanges = [
        {
          count = 1;
          startGid = config.ids.gids."${config.users.users.username.group}";
        }
      ];
      subUidRanges = [
        {
          count = 1;
          startUid = config.users.users.username.uid;
        }
      ];
    };
    username = {
      isNormalUser = true;
      uid = 1000;
    };
  };
```

Strangely, `config.users.users.username.group` seems to resolve fine even though I've not set it explicitly, but I still had to set `config.users.users.username.uid` to fix this issue:

> error: The option value `users.users.root.subUidRanges.[definition 2-entry 1].startUid' in`/etc/nixos/common.nix' is not of type `signed integer'.